# Event generation on gridview field click in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have view user field in grid view. So, when i click on view user text 
,it should generate me popup in which I enter user ID, if userID is correct, only then it will allow to navigate to other page containing that user details.
I am able to navigate to other Url using NavigateUrl, but not able to generate event.

My code is as below:

```
 protected void grdPage_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (grdPage.RowHeaderColumn.Contains("View"))
        {
            Response.Redirect("../Login.aspx?");

        }
    }
```

Comment: The code I have just populates grid view, I dont think that will be relevant to this, as I am not able to generate event on click of field.

Comment: grdPage_SelectedIndexChanged, this is only event i am able to get when i click on grid field, but I need specific event for particular field in grid view, still i will post my code

Answer (score 0):

Use OnRowCommand for this purpose.

Comment: Let me do it, will get back to you

Comment: I have edited my my question, hopefully you will get what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery/javascript to open the popup

like this

```
 <a  href="javascript:;" title="View" onclick="javascript:return openModal(<%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "userID ")%>);">View</a>
```